# Writing information to mongoDB from facebook using Tornado

Tags: python, facebook, mongodb, tornado

I am using tornado to access Facebook using code provided in "introduction to tornado" book and I want to write certain information to monogDB. So I have created a wrapper around Mongodb in another module like this

```
class MongoDB:

    def __init__(self,dbname):
        self._conn = pymongo.Connection("localhost", 27017)
        self._db   = self._conn[dbname]

    def createCollection(self, name=""):
        return self._db[name]

    def insertRecord(self,collection,document):
        self._collection.insert(document)
```

and I am trying to write Username,accesstoken and UserID to database. I have added the code to loginhandler class like this:

```
class LoginHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler, tornado.auth.FacebookGraphMixin):
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def get(self):
    userID = self.get_secure_cookie('user_id')
    if self.get_argument('code', None):
        self.get_authenticated_user(
            redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/fb/auth/login',
            client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
            client_secret=self.settings['facebook_secret'],
            code=self.get_argument('code'),
            callback=self.async_callback(self._on_facebook_login))
        return
    elif self.get_secure_cookie('access_token'):
        self.redirect('/fb')

    self.authorize_redirect(
        redirect_uri='http://localhost:8000/fb/auth/login',
        client_id=self.settings['facebook_api_key'],
        extra_params={'scope': 'read_stream,publish_stream'}
    )



def _on_facebook_login(self, user):
    if not user:
        self.clear_all_cookies()
        raise tornado.web.HTTPError(500, 'Facebook authentication failed')

    self.set_secure_cookie('user_id', str(user['id']))
    self.set_secure_cookie('user_name', str(user['name']))
    self.set_secure_cookie('access_token', str(user['access_token']))
    self.redirect('/fb')

    database = MongoDB('UserDatabase')
    CredentialCollection = database.createCollection("UserCredential")
    Credential = {"UserID": str(user['user_id']), "Username": str(user['Username']) ,"access_token": str(user['access_token']), "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
    CredentialCollection.insert(Credential)
```

And I am getting error:

```
line 85, in LoginHandler
Credential = {"UserID": self.str(user['user_id']), "Username": str(user['Username']) ,"access_token": str(user['access_token']), "date": datetime.datetime.utcnow()}
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

any idea what I am doing wrong here ?

Comment: Line 85 in exception and line in code are not the same. Have you restarted tornado after changes?

Answer (score 0):

The error is `{"UserID": self.str(user['user_id'])` ,but it's not the same with your code.Just restart your tornado server.